# How to find period from graph

Tags: graphics, periodic-function

Code is:

```
m[t_] := {mx[t], my[t], mz[t]}

γ = 28;
h = 6.62*10^-34;
e = 1.6*10^-19;

Subscript[μ, 0] = 1.25*10^-6;
Subscript[μM, 0] = 800*10^-3;
Subscript[M, 0] = 0.64*10^6;
Subscript[r, 0] = 100*10^-9;
Subscript[l, 0] = 3*10^-9;
Subscript[I, dc] = 1*10^-3;
Subscript[B, dc] = 200*10^-3;
Subscript[α, G] = 0.01;

p = {0, 0, 1};
σ =(γ*h/2*e)*1/(Subscript[M, 0]*Pi*(Subscript[r, 0])^2)*Subscript[l, 0];
Subscript[B, eff] = {Subscript[B, dc], 0, 0}-Subscript[μM, 0]*(m[t]*p);

system1 ={D[m[t], t] ==γ*(Cross[Subscript[B, eff], m[t]]) + Subscript[α, 
G]*(Cross[m[t], D[m[t], t]]) +σ*Subscript[I, dc]*(Cross[m[t], Cross[m[t], 
p]]),(m[t] /. t -> 0) == {0, 1, 0}};

s1 = NDSolve[system1, m[t], {t, 0, 50}]

Plot[Evaluate[{mx[t], my[t], mz[t]} /. s1], {t, 0, 50},AxesLabel -> {t, m}]
```

How can i find each period from this graph?

```
Plot[Evaluate[mx[t] /. s1], {t, 0, 50}, AxesLabel -> {t, mx}]
```

[image]

Comment: ps. `PlotPoints -> 1000` will fix up the plot.

Comment: Сan you explain in more detail? I divided my t on 10 as a result i have 10 graph with t 5nsec

Comment: `PlotPoints` just tells `Plot` to increase its sampling. With the default it is missing parts of the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the period by forcing the solver to find all the local extrema:

```
z = Reap[s1 = 
     NDSolve[{system1, WhenEvent[mx'[t] == 0, Sow[t]]}, 
      m[t], {t, 0, 50}]][[2, 1]];
ListPlot[Differences[z[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]]]
```

[image]

or on a time axis..

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{#, Differences[Prepend[#, 0]]} &@ 
   z[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]]]
```

[image]

incedentally we can plot the actual numerical solution results instead of letting `Plot` sample the interpolation function:

```
 ListPlot[Transpose[{Flatten[#["Grid"]], #["ValuesOnGrid"]}], 
    Joined -> True] &@((mx[t] /. First@s1)[[0]])
```

[image]

Comment: I like the way you used NDSolve. I used FindRoot but it was far more inaccurate. Thanks.